# How to get data from Qlikview when using extensions?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, qlikview

I have the following extension which is working perfectly when the data is present within the function itself. However, whenever I am trying to use a loop to get data from Qlikview, it gives me a blank output. Can anyone please help me with this? In the below code I have commented out the section where I have given the data in the function itself. Please help.

```
Qva.LoadScript("http://www.google.com/jsapi?callback=loadGoogleCoreChart", function () {
});

 function loadGoogleCoreChart() {
google.load('visualization', '1', {
    packages: ['corechart'],
    callback: googleCoreChartLoaded
});
 }

function googleCoreChartLoaded() {

Qva.AddExtension('QlikView/Examples/GooglePieChart', function () {

    //Declaring a two dimensional array (an array of arrays)
    var row = new Array(this.Data.Rows.length + 1);
    for (var i = 0; i <= this.Data.Rows.length; i++) {
        row[i] = new Array(2);
    }
    //Getting the data from QlikView-- this part is not working!
    for (var j = 1; j <= this.Data.Rows.length; j++) {
        row[j][0] = this.Data.Rows[j - 1][0].text;

        var temp = this.Data.Rows[j - 1][1].text;
        row[j][1] = Number(temp);
    }

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(row);
    alert("hello");
    /*
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
      ['Work',     11],
      ['Eat',      2],
      ['Commute',  2],
      ['Watch TV', 2],
      ['Sleep',    7]
    ]);
    */

    new google.visualization.PieChart(this.Element).draw(data, { chartArea: { left: 20, top: 20, width: "100%", height: "100%"} });
});
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when building arrays in JavaScript,
it is not necessary to define / create all the array elements before populating the values

also, when using a `for` loop in this manner, for the second argument,
need to use less than (`<`)
not less than or equal (`<=`)

otherwise, the loop will fail on the last element, given they are zero based

if you have an array with 2 elements, their indexes will be zero and one
e.g. -- `arr[0]` -- `arr[1]`

so when `i` is equal to `length` 2 -- `arr[2]` will not exist

try something like the following snippet...

```
Qva.AddExtension('QlikView/Examples/GooglePieChart', function () {
    var row = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < this.Data.Rows.length; i++) {
      row.push([
        this.Data.Rows[i][0].text,
        parseFloat(this.Data.Rows[i][1].text)
      ]);
    }

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(row, true);
    new google.visualization.PieChart(this.Element).draw(data, { chartArea: { left: 20, top: 20, width: "100%", height: "100%"} });
});
```

note: if you're array doesn't have column headings for the first row, need to add `true` as the second argument to --> `arrayToDataTable`

Comment: Thank You so much. This definitely helped :)